# Need folder structure for Flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I would like to have two flavors named free and paid for my application

So this is how my prohect structure looks like

```
project/
└── src/
    ├── Free/
    │   ├── java/
    │   │   └── com.abc.free
    │   │        ├── classA.java
    │   │        └── classB.java
    │   ├── res/
    │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
    │
    ├── main
    │   ├── java/
    │   │   └── com.abc.main
    │   │        ├── classA.java
    │   │        └── classB.java
    │   │                 
    │   ├── res/
    │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
    │              
    └── Paid/
        ├── java/
        │   └── com.abc
        │       ├── classA.java
        │       └── classB.java
        ├── res/
        └── AndroidManifest.xml
```

All three have the same classes but obviously there are some changes in paid version.

Now my questions are

1) Is the project structure is right ? Or do I need to make any changes

2) Do I need to remove the classes from main as its giving me errors as there are duplicate classes

and what will be my default application Id  is it com.abc ? com.abc.free or is it com.abc.paid ?

Answer (score -2):

Your structure is incorrect. You cannot have the same class in multiple flavours. You can have a base class in main MainActivityBase.java that has the common functionality in it and then override this class in each flavour with flavour specific code.

You also should only have one manifest file.

Comment: This is not true. You can have the same Java class defined in two flavors as long as the two are never used at the same time (e.g. if they are in different flavor dimensions it can be a problem, but if they are in the same flavor dimension it will work fine). You cannot define the same class in `main` and a flavor either.

Comment: Fair enough. So you can have ClassA in paid and free, but you cannot have ClassA in main as well. You could have a ClassABase in main that is extended in paid and free i.e.: ClassA extends ClassABase